# Why is the default value of a function 1?

Tags: c++, function, c++14, function-pointers, default-value

I noticed that the constructor with parentheses behaves differently, at least for floats and ints.

```
// int a, b{}, c = T(), d = T{}, e();
float a, b{}, c = T(), d = T{}, e();
endl(std::cout << a << ", " << b << ", " << c << ", " << d << ", " << e);

// 0, 0, 0, 0, 1
```

It's not a default constructor, the parentheses were parsed as part of the type. I printed the types, and `e` has type `float (&)()` (or just `float()` with proper forwarding), so I think it's a default-constructed function. The result of calling it has a type, but calling it results in the linker error you'd expect. Its value would be 0 if it were a function pointer. Why would its value be 1, or how does it end up as 1 when it's printed?

Comment: "I think it's a default-constructed function". It is just a function. Nothing is "default-constructed" there and there no need to "construct" anything.

Comment: I see that from the linker error, but I assumed from the printed value that it had to have some value of its own. I didn't realize I was printing a function pointer.

Comment: As an aside, I made `Wrapper<int> e()` which constructs `int value` with perfect forwarding. `value` is 1. Is that the same thing happening, is `int()` decayed to `int (*)()` and to `bool` before it becomes `int`? I even added `Wrapper<S>::Wrapper(void)`, and only `Wrapper<S> e = Wrapper<S>()` resulted in `value==0`.

Comment: I tried extra parentheses to avoid the function parse, as in `Wrapper<int> (e())`, but the value is still 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a function pointer, it's literally a function (albeit an undefined one).

By streaming the expression `e`, which decays, you're *creating* a pointer to that function, and said pointer is valid because it points to the function you've declared called `e`. Hence, `1`.

You're right to say that if you declared a function pointer to begin with, and made it `nullptr`, you'd see `0` instead by streaming it. But functions and function pointers are two different things.

Comment: Hence, `1`? Are you saying it prints as a boolean?

Comment: Actually that's exactly what happens. Sorry I doubted you!

Comment: @JohnP Yep that's right

Answer (score 3):

```
float e();
```

This declares e as a function that returns float and takes no arguments. So This decays to a function pointer which decays to bool which prints 1 unless `boolalpha` is set.